# Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 and Google Hangout (talkplugin)

Tags: ubuntu, google-talk

I am trying to get Hangout <strike>with my camera</strike> to work with Quantal. I got the plugin from the PPA here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_talk_plugin and I also tried downloading it from google before.

- Video does work with both cheese and skype.
- I tried preloading v4l1-compat.so
- I tried preloading v4l2-convert.so
- I tried everything in both chromium-browser and firefox

However, the camera does not even activate. It is detected in the hangout settings, but the led stays off. **After closer inspection and some tests, I found out that audio does not work either; the browser window with Hangout just closes after a while, and I can neither see nor hear my conversation partner and vice-versa.**

Can anyone point me at how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Edit: on Arch Linux (x86_64) this works without hassle by installing the plugin from AUR. So, it must be possible somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact symptoms you report and found a solution that worked for me here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chat/i-found-a-bug/video-chat/DEXY2m6-i5M

The bottom line is all versions of the Google Talk Plug-in after v3.7 have some bug the prevents them working for many people using Ubuntu. Install the old v3.7 version worked for me and several others. v3.9 and v.10 are known bad. Hopefully v3.11 work include a fix.

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_talk_plugin